# How to access Windows 10 NTFS contents?

Tags: release-freya

I used to be able to open up the Files program and read/write/delete/update any file on my Windows disks/partitions.

Now, the drives/partitions appear in Files, but nothing happens when I click on them. I think this might have started happening after I went to Freya.

Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue isn't about elementary OS.  It's about Windows 10 and it fast boot mode.

You can find a solution here:

[how mount Windows Ntfs partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/408622)

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes, this does work if you see the drives in 'Files', you click on it and it takes you back to your root.  Thank you for a working solution.